# Dependent dropdown in symfony

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I've been trying for w hile to make a dependent dropdown in symfony, I saw [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#cookbook-form-events-submitted-data) post in the symfony documentation and I followed it, the only think that I don't understand in here:

```
$formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Sport $sport = null) {
        $positions = null === $sport ? array() : $sport->getAvailablePositions();

        $form->add('position', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'       => 'AppBundle:Position',
            'placeholder' => '',
            'choices'     => $positions,
        ));
    };
```

Where does the getAvailablePositions should be defined? and how it would look like? I'm really lost and have been since a while. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Btw. by dependent dropdown I mean is like in the symfony document you have two dropdowns, one with sports and the other with positions, then you select soccer, and after that the second one populates with positions like goalkeeper, defense, attack, ...

EDIT:

This is my javascript

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#sport").change(function(){
            var data = {
                option_id: $(this).val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '{{ path("positions") }}',
                data: data,
                success: function(data) {
                    var $position_select = $('#positions');

                    $position_select.html('<option>positions</option>');

                    for (var i=0, total = data.length; i < total; i++) {
                        $position_select.append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
                    }
                    $position_select.html('');
                    $.each(data, function(k, v) {
                        $position_select.append('<option value="' + v + '">' + k + '</option>');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using event subscribers. Pretty good tutorial here http://showmethecode.es/php/symfony/symfony2-4-dependent-forms/

Comment: I try this but i cant get the second option to change. :/  I think it might be the database, because when I use php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force it says that there is nothing to change even if I modify the entities. In this app we use .orm.yml files for the database structure. Any ideas?

Comment: It kind of works now, the problem now its that it only shows the options when I press the submit button. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you add Javascript code to do partial posts via AJAX as per that tutorial?